# Google login works on localhost but not on online domain

Tags: php, openid, google-oauth, google-openid, lightopenid

I am using lighopenID `https://gitorious.org/lightopenid` which works fine at my local host. And always validates:

```
include 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID('localhost');
$checkvalidation = $openid->validate();
```

But when I made the code online and as per the documentation I replaced `localhost` with my domain name `domainname.com` then it keeps on giving me this error:

OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain: http://domainname.com

Kindly let me know how can I fix this issue?

```
include 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID('domainname.com');
$checkvalidation = $openid->validate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use OpenID, use OAuth 2 instead. As you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable), Google has deprecated the OpenID 2 API and closed registration to new clients in May 2014.